# beamer with notes displayed while giving a presentation

Tags: beamer, notes

What are people currently using to have notes available while giving a presentation?

[This](http://www.guidodiepen.nl/2009/07/creating-latex-beamer-handouts-with-notes/comment-page-1/) post shows how to have a notes section for taking notes (audience oriented).  I guess the presenter could also have a copy and with their notes written in on what they would like to say.  However, that's manual writing.

I'm also aware of the \note feature of Beamer (see [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Presentations)) where you can generate slides of notes.  However, to make it useful, I have to have \note section after each slide, including the title slide, in order to print say 6 slides per page (3 main slides on left, 3 notes slide on right), or something like that.

I'm curious on what other people are using for notes.  Thanks!

Anyone using dual screen, where the main screen shows the presentation, and where the second screen shows the presentation and notes?  It is outlined [here](http://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2010-1/dohmen/dohmen.pdf) but I'm not sure how to follow.

Comment: In general, open-ended questions like this one don't fare well on SE sites (as maybe you've found by the number of answers!).  If there's a particular aspect of making a presentation-with-notes that you would like to do but can't then please ask a more focussed question on that.  For the current question, my best answer would be "I use a piece of paper!".